# Main method empty?

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I have a class that implements Runnable, but Eclipse needs a public static void main method in it. Is it ok if the main is completly empty?

```
public class Launcher implements Runnable{
private String message;

public Launcher(String message) {

    this.message= message;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
}

@Override
public void run() {

//My implementations
}
```

Comment: How do you want to launch your application then? Of course, if it is a webservice you do not need the main method. But having an executable jar/exe you have to use the main method as this is your entry point.

Comment: @ArthurEirich I lauch it in another class with new Launcher(telegram).run();

Comment: Main methods and Runnables are basic concepts of Java. A fast google search will yield all you need to know.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't need a `main` in your `Runnable`, Eclipse needs a `main` to launch an application ! An entry point to your program if you prefer. A `Runnable` and `main` aren't related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you intend `Launcher` to be the main class of the application, the one you use to start it, the main method is needed and must do whatever should be done to start work.

If not, delete the main method. Eclipse does not require a main method unless you start the application by telling it to run the class. It will optionally generate one when creating a class, but that can be edited out if not needed.

Comment: yes, Launcher is not my main class. And I deleted the main from Launcher class, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `main` method is the only method the compiler is searching for when looking where to start. Hence if you're `main` method is empty, nothing gets executed. At the very least add:

```
new Launcher("some string").run();
```

in the main method.